# Selecting layers in group using PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, layers

This script is applied to all layers on the TOC, and I want to improve it to apply only to layers of a specific group

```
# Create an empty table in memory and add fields
newtable = QgsVectorLayer("None", "Results", "memory")
provider = newtable.dataProvider()
provider.addAttributes([QgsField('Layername', QVariant.String),
                        QgsField('Length', QVariant.Double)])
newtable.updateFields()

# For each table added to the map calculate length and 
# add layername and length to the created table
for lyr in QgsProject.instance().mapLayers().values():
    f = QgsFeature()
    total_length = sum([r.geometry().length() for r in lyr.getFeatures()]) #Possible to round decimals here
    f.setAttributes([lyr.name(), total_length])
    provider.addFeature(f)
    
QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(newtable)
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use the following lines:

```
newtable = QgsVectorLayer("None", "Results", "memory")
provider = newtable.dataProvider()
provider.addAttributes([QgsField('Layername', QVariant.String),
                        QgsField('Length', QVariant.Double)])
newtable.updateFields()

# find group
group_name = "group2" # specify group name
root = QgsProject.instance().layerTreeRoot()
group = root.findGroup(group_name)

# layer list in the group
layers_in_group = [layer.layer() for layer in group.children()]

for lyr in layers_in_group:
    total_length = sum([r.geometry().length() for r in lyr.getFeatures()])
    
    f = QgsFeature()
    f.setAttributes([lyr.name(), total_length])
    provider.addFeatures([f])

QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(newtable, False)

root.insertLayer(0, newtable)
```

Comment: Thanks so much, bro! It's exactly what I'm looking for. Thanks again

Comment: another question please, the upper part of the script is to add a new table, but it's added inside the group, how can I edit to add the table outside the group at the top of TOC? because I'm applying other processing scripts to the group and this way it will be applied also to the table, Thanks in advance

Comment: By default, QGIS places the new layer on top of the selected layer.

Comment: but inside the group, I want to add it outside to avoid including it in further processing script

Comment: I've edited the answer. Add the last four lines to your script.

Comment: It's adding two tables, one inside and one outside. Maybe we can define first where to add the table.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/133273/discussion-between-ahmed-kamel-and-kadir-sahbaz).

Comment: It's great bro! but I want to perform other processes before merging.

Comment: Sorry, copy/paste typo

Comment: no problem, it's also a good hint